# Create Packages Automatically From Installers chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

Pls! I want to convert .exe to .nupkg or .nuspec with choco new --file  . But i have error : 
 Error converted to warning:
(183) Cannot create a file when that file already exists: [\?\C:\tools\chocolatey.server\App_Data\Packages\UniKeyNT.exe]

[image]

Comment: Message clear says: ***Cannot create a file when that file already exists***. Please check the path.

Comment: The path is correct . it is exist . but it warning msg .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, it would seem like you are using the Open Source version of Chocolatey, is that correct?  If so, please read the documentation [here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-new):

> --file, --url=VALUE
>
> Location of binary. In [Chocolatey for Business](https://chocolatey.org/compare), file is used for auto-detection (native installer, zip, patch/upgrade file, or remote url to download first) to completely create a package with proper silent arguments! Can be 32-bit or 64-bit architecture.  Available in licensed editions only (licensed version 1.4.0+, url/zip starting in 1.6.0). See https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-create-packages-from-installers

i.e. the parameter that you are trying to use isn't available in the version of Chocolatey that you are using.

If you are using Chocolatey for Business, looks like your license hasn't been installed correctly.

Comment: That's weird, it's supposed to detect the use of `--file` and provide a more helpful error. :/